# Opening a .map file

Tags: .map

I have received a spatial data file with .map extension.
Using file archiver software I can see the data contains files with .lyr, .mak, .mav., mtg, .mtx, and .stx as pictured in the screenshot:

[image]

I have tried Data Interoperability Tools in ArcGIS but the format is unrecognized.

Any recommendation on how to access that file?

Comment: Did you ask the sender of the data?

Comment: It was an old archive from my office and the creator of the file is uncontactable.

Comment: .mav is a virtual table for MS Access - so it possible this is are a Visual Studio/C++ project files. Can you open the files in a text editor?

Comment: It said "unsupported text encoding". Using notepad shows unreadable text.

Comment: .map sounds like MapServer

Answer (score 0):

It could be an old Navigon GPS system.

The only link I could find, with reference to a *.map is here:

https://www.navitotal.com/maps-for-navigon/navigon-europe-2016-fresh-maps-mn7-mn8-t19216-30.html

This appears to be a converter:

https://www.gpspower.net/navigon/318773-nfs-extractor-tool.html

I have never come across this type of file before.

Another option may be a MapINFO file.